# Как передать referer в django.auth.views.login?

Tags: django

На любой странице, если пользователь не авторизован, есть линк на авторизацию.
Использую django.contrib.auth

В [urls.py](http://urls.py) такое:

> url(r'login$', login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),

В шаблоне можно задать ссылку на страницу, куда переходит пользователь после авторизации.
Но никак не могу сообразить, как там вытащить referer, т.к. request в шаблоне нету

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Документация Django](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4/ref/request-response.html#django.http.HttpRequest.META) + `django.core.context_processors.request` в `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Comment: Точно, процессор забыл :)